What is the Difference Between Redis FT Search and Normal Redis Caching String Key?
Recently i'm building backend system with spring boot framework and i found 2 ways to use redis as a caching for my app
1- use normal feature of redis caching O(1) ( key and value )
2- using redis ft search and store each table of my db as document representation
and i want to know the key difference between them and when should i use both of them ?

If you only intend to look up your data by key, then key lookup is the most effective way to go (e.g. you store a user sesssion in Redis, use the userid as a key and only ever look up the session data by user)
On the other hand, if you want to search based on the content of the data, iterating over all the keys and looking at all the data would be extremely inefficient, whilst an index would very efficiently obtain all keys whose data  content matches your search (e.g. if in the user session example you want to find all users who have a particular product stored within the session in their shopping cart to target a promotional offer)
In addition, other search use cases such as geographical searches or vector searches would simply be impossible with key alone.

Ok but i didn't get, if i want to stick to the basics if i don't know what is the ft search, can i make an endpoint as the example u provided GET /users/carts/products/{id} which wil intrgratate the users service and carts, products which the pattern should i use to figure out that this situation required ft search ?
